# how does user program pin pages? and what is page buffer? (in an LWN article about get_user_pages)

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

While reading https://lwn.net/Articles/774411/ I found this sentence.

> An application pins pages in memory, which causes the kernel to use
> get_user_pages() or similar to map the user-space memory into the
> kernel's address space.

I thought it is the driver that pins the page but this says the application pins the pages and the driver uses get_user_pages() from the pinned adderss.  How can I pin the address in user space program?
And the article says,

> The underlying problem is that the page buffers can be stripped off
> while the page is pinned and undergoing I/O;

Why is the page buffer stripped off when the page is pinned? Is the page buffer the one used for block devices(not the physical page)?

Answer (score 3):

**Page Buffer**

Although the page cache and the buffer cache are different disk caches, in Version 2.4 of Linux, they are somewhat intertwined. In fact, for reasons of efficiency, buffers are not allocated as single memory objects; instead, buffers are stored in dedicated pages called buffer pages. All the buffers within a single buffer page must have the same size; hence, on the 80 x 86 architecture, a buffer page can include from one to eight buffers, depending on the block size.

Refer to these official websites for more details.

1. https://www.halolinux.us/kernel-reference/buffer-pages.html
2. https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/pin_user_pages.html